# Ionic cannot emulate ios

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework, emulation

The build was successful but I can't emulate it:

[image]

When i want to check the file, the 'platform/ios/build' folder doesn't even exist

[image]

I'm using osx Mojave btw

Comment: did you used "ionic cordova build ios" command?..

Comment: yes I did use that command

Comment: did u get build successful message?.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see any

Comment: Check if there is any error in console

Comment: So it's actually unsuccessful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182913/discussion-between-anandh-sp-and-alvseek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using XCode 10, and to run it you need to add flag:

```
# Cordova CLI
cordova run ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'
cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'

# Ionic CLI
ionic cordova run ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/407